# How do you change the elements within an NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I am a bit confused as to how arrays are handled in Objective-C.
If I have an array such as

```
NSarray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc]
                                  initWithObjects:@"N", @"N", @"N", @"N", @"N",
                                  nil];
```

how do I change the first occurrence to "Y"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need an NSMutableArray ..

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]
                                  initWithObjects:@"N", @"N", @"N", @"N", @"N",
                                  nil];
```

and then

```
[myArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@"Y"];
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't, because `NSArray` is immutable. But if you use `NSMutableArray` instead, then you can. See [`replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:):

```
[myArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@"Y"]
```

Answer (score 4):

Write a helper method

```
-(NSArray *)replaceObjectAtIndex:(int)index inArray:(NSArray *)array withObject:(id)object {
    NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [array mutableCopy];
    mutableArray[index] = object;
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableArray];
}
```

Now you can test this method with

```
NSArray *arr = @[@"a", @"b", @"c"];
arr = [self replaceObjectAtIndex:1 inArray:arr withObject:@"d"];
logObject(arr);
```

This outputs

```
arr = (
    a,
    d,
    c
)
```

You can use similar method for NSDictionary

```
-(NSDictionary *)replaceObjectWithKey:(id)key inDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict withObject:(id)object {
    NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [dict mutableCopy];
    mutableDict[key] = object;
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:mutableDict];
}
```

You can test it with

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"name": @"Albert", @"salary": @3500};
dict = [self replaceObjectWithKey:@"salary" inDictionary:dict withObject:@4400];
logObject(dict);
```

which outputs

```
dict = {
    name = Albert;
    salary = 4400;
}
```

You could even add this as a category and have it easily available.